# $\sigma_A(\zeta \cap A)= \sigma(\zeta) \cap A$, where $\zeta$ is a class of subsets of $\Omega$ and $A \subset \Omega $.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am reading Robert Ash's book Probability and measure theory. But am unable to understand the proof of this statement. Specifically the line $\sigma(\zeta) \cap A$  is a $\sigma$ field of subsets of A. I assume it is critical in next proofs so I thought if someone could suggest an alternative proof the above statement.

Comment: Nite that the intersection of two $\sigma$-fields is a $\sigma$-field.